# Removing write protection for micro sd card

Tags: sd-card, write-protect

I am trying to remove the write protection from my micro sd card. I have opened the command prompt and used diskpart. When i try to cleani get an error

```
diskpart has encountered an error the request could not be performed because of an i/o device error
```

how do i prevent this error and how would i remove the write protection. any methods?

Comment: Since you haven’t volunteered the information, I’ll ask the obvious (potentially ’’dumb’’) question: Have you checked for a physical write-protect switch on the card?  It’s typically a slider.

Answer (score 1):

When you get write protection errors from a micro sd card here is a good chance the card has gone into protection mode and is hence forth unusable, there is no physical write protection on Micro SD cards. You can probably copy off the data but that's about it. If you can't format it in Windows then try doing it in a camera or other device, if that also fails then you know the card is tickets/bust.